Google Analytics API for getting total clicks and impression
I want a total click and impression for the google analytics api for where we can get the total impression and click.
I am using this url to fetch the data from the google but i didn't find any api from where we can get the data by passing query and get the result.
https://search.google.com/search-console/performance/search-analytics
